# Require one of several values

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

I have a table with 5 boolean columns. I want to force the user to pick at least one. Is there a way to do this using the CakePHP `$validator` object in the Table PHP?

I can accomplish this in the controller easy enough, but utilizing the built-in stuff seems less wrong. Nothing in the docs jumps out at me. .

Controller example:

```
if (false === $val1 === $val2 === $val3 === $val4 === $val5){
   //return with error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to be a situation for a rule, not a validation.

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules) {
    $rules->add(function (EntityInterface $entity, Array $options) {
        return $entity->val1 || $entity->val2 || $entity->val3 || $entity->val4 || $entity->val5;
    }, 'selectOne', [
        'errorField' => 'val1',
        'message' => __('You must select at least one of these fields.'),
    ]);

    return $rules;
}
```